# How to iterate over JS array to create even cols in a row

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, reactjs

I am not sure how to do this.  I am using something similar to a bootstrap grid with col-3,4,6 etc...
I have a JS array with pics and I need to put these in a col-4 inside of a row.  The rows have their own styling, so this is necessary.
How can I iterate through an array to put out something like this:

```
array = [
  item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8
]

array.map(function(item){
  //puts code here
});

returns
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4">
    item1
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    item2
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    item3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4">
    item4
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    item5
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    item6
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4">
    item7
  </div>
  <div class="col4">
    item8
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using react components btw.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. @depperm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vnLp2sfs/3/

```
function grid( array, colc, rowstyle, colstyle ) {

    var result = "";

    array.forEach(function(item, index, self){
      var i = index % colc; // Column index

      if (i===0) result += '<div class="'+rowstyle+'">'; // Open row

      result += '<div class="'+colstyle+'">' + item + '</div>';

      if (i===(colc-1) || index === self.length-1 ) result += '</div>'; // Close row    
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this (assuming we're in a React component and are not using ES6):

```
getDefaultProps: function(){
    return {
      cellsPerRow: 3,  
      myArray: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8']
    };
},

renderRow: function(cells){
    return (
        <div className="row">
            {cells.map(function(item) {
                return <div className="col4">{item}</div>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
},

render: function(){
    var array = this.props.myArray.slice();
    var output = [];
    var cellsInRow;

    while (array.length) {
        cellsInRow = array.splice(0,this.props.cellsPerRow);   
        output.push(
            this.renderRow(cellsInRow)
        );
    }

    return <div>{output}</div>;
},
```

Takes advantage of the way splice works, in that it is destructive of the subject array and returns the spliced indices.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7', 'item8'];

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  $('.col4:eq('+i+')').html(array[i]);
  
  }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
  <div class="col4">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two typos:

1. `V` isn't a thing
2. Using `col-md-4` instead of `col4`

The following will take your array (`array`), use `.map()` to wrap the column classes around each item, chunk the array into sets of at most 3 items, then compile the HTML by looping through the chunked array and wrapping each set in a row class.

```
var array = [
  'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'
];

array = array.map(function (item) {
  return '  <div class="col-md-4">' + item + '</div>\n';
});

array = [].concat.apply([], array.map(function(elem,i) {
  return i % 3 ? [] : [array.slice(i, i + 3)];
}));

var html = ''

array.forEach(function (set) {
  html += '<div class="row">\n';
  html += set.join('');
  html += '</div>\n';
});

console.write(html);
```

Output (`html` variable):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">item1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">item2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">item3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">item4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed the typos.  But the `col-4` is what I'm using.  I'm not using bootstrap, I'm using something similar.